# Laravel 5 Sort eloquent model with relationships

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, subquery

I have a model that I want to sort based on a relationship property.

The main model, `Resultado`, has a relation `respondente`, of type `belongsTo`, and `respondente` has a relation `usuario`.

I want to get `Resultado` with those relations and sort the results by `usuario` `name` property (column).

I tried

```
$resultados = Diagnostico\Resultado::with('respondente.usuario')
    ->orderBy('usuarios.name')->get();
```

but that trows a "Column not found 'usuarios.name'" mysql error.

How can I sort the `Resultado` model based on its relationships?

**EDIT**:

The table for `Resultado` model is `diag_resultados`. As I wrote in the comments, I had to use join to achieve the right result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a sub query

```
 $resultados = Diagnostico\Resultado::with(['respondente.usuario' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('usuarios.name', 'asc');
    }])->get();
```

something like that should work

Comment: The query have been well formed. But the results (`->get()`) still come not sorted by name. The order changes but is not in ascendant order, what is weird.

Comment: In fact, the results come sorted by `Resultado` `id`.

Comment: I think Laravel 5 Eloquent ORM does not know how to deal with sub-relations like that to encapsulate such `orderBy` method in the last relation and go backward to sort the first model. Anybody correct me if I'm wrong. I solved the problem with join applied in my Eloquent model.

Answer (score 2):

Using `join` instead `with` works.

```
$resultados = Diagnostico\Resultado::join('usuarios', 'diag_resultados.respondente_id', '=', 'usuarios.perfil_id')->get()->sortBy('name');
```